# How to pattern match a function?

Tags: smlnj

H,

I am trying to do pattern matching, but the input to the function is a curried function, how can you pattern match something like that?

Can anyone show me some examples please?

Comment: Perhaps you could supply an example, to clarify you question

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you are trying to pattern match the function you get as input?

That is not possible. A function doesn't have a structure so it doesn't really make sense to try and do that.